# Underscore.js debounce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I try to debounce a function using Underscore.js 1.6.0 but the function isn't called after the timeout set. I expect exactly one "o" in the output div, but there is none. Changing `_.debounce(echo, 200)` to `_.debounce(echo(), 200)` produces 10 o's which is not what I want. Same result on Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using _.debounce in the wrong way?

See http://jsfiddle.net/YmSGL/ for a working example.

```
function echo() {
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML + "o";       
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Calling echo @" + _.now());
        _.debounce(echo, 200);
    }, wait);
}
```

Comment: `_.debounce` **returns** a new function. That's the function you have to call. Have a look at the example in the documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Felix Kling! The following code works:

```
function echo() {
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML + "o";       
}

var echo2 = _.debounce(echo, 200);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Calling echo @" + _.now());
        echo2();
    }, wait);
}
```

If you would excuse me now, I have to bang my head to the wall.